# Why is SHA256 and invalid hash algorithm when signing with RSA?

Tags: rsa, signing, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am trying to sign a stream using the method below but I always get a Cryptographic Exception saying that it is not a valid hash algorithm even though it is listed in the documentation:

```
byte[] SignData(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa, Stream stream, string hashName)
{
    HashAlgorithm hash = HashAlgorithm.Create(hashName);
    byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(stream, hash);
    return signature;
}
```

I am calling it with "SHA256" as the hashName parameter. and the exception is thrown at the line where rsa.SignData() is called.

This is NOT using X509 certificates, it is not a duplicate. BTW see answer below.

Comment: FYI, there is also [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Invalid algorithm specified" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433074/why-am-i-getting-invalid-algorithm-specified-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resolved and **it is not a duplicate** because I am using the plain *RSACryptoServiceProvider* of .NET and not X509 certificates.

I ran into this post:
http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-fix-invalid-algorithm-specified-when-signing-with-sha256/

Reading it it occurred to me to to examine the RSA SignatureAlgorithm and it the resulting URI indicated it was **SHA1** so no SHA256 or SHA512. Then I looked up that property in MSDN documentation and it says that property always returns that value because it only supports that, so only **SHA1**.

Answer (score 2):

Software-backed `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is only capable of doing RSA signature using a SHA-2 digest algorithm when the CSP ProviderType value is 24 (PROV_RSA_AES) and the ProviderName is "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" (MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV).  Hardware may or may not require PROV_RSA_AES, just depends on the hardware.

`RSACng` can always do RSA signature using a SHA-2 digest (unless hardware backed and the hardware refuses to, but that seems unlikely), and `RSACng` is also capable of doing RSA OAEP encryption using a SHA-2 digest (`RSACryptoServiceProvider` only has PKCS#1 v1.5 and OAEP-SHA-1), and RSA PSS signature.

But `RSACryptoServiceProvider` was the only builtin RSA provider for so long that it took until .NET Framework 4.6.2 to get the whole of the framework happy with accepting `RSACng` (added in 4.6).

As for the `SignatureAlgorithm` property, it's hard-coded to be the SHA-1 XML value.  You can't extract any information from it. (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsacryptoserviceprovider.cs,e4a5c015070c0714)